# Spark stores wrong last day of month into mysql

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I am using spark and my task is to write the last day of month into mysql. But I had some problem with the timezone. My system is in UTC+8 timezone and mysql is in UTC+0 timezone.

The spark code is fairly straightforward

`val randomDay = args(0)
 val temp = spark.sql(s"""select last_day('$randomDay') as lastday from .....""")`

But when I looked at the mysql table, it shows 2019/3/30, which is one day off. I tried `temp.show()`, and it shows the correct date 2019/3/31.

I know it has something to do with timezone but I don't know how to fix it.
Also, the column type of mysql table is date, which shouldn't depend on timezone.

Comment: Please show us what happens to `temp` after your SQL call.  Most likely, there is an adjustment which is moving the last day back by one day.

Comment: Is $today from the table? If not, try using the SQL version of time - `SELECT LAST_DAY(NOW()) AS lastdate...`. If `$today` is from a SQL data then you'll definitely need to read how [mysql timezones are handled](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: @danblack today is a parameter provided by user. I changed the name to randomDay now

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I tried temp.show() and it shows the correct result. But when I write it to mysql it shows one day off.